# CSS styles get impacted when I force my application from document mode IE5 to a higher version (like IE 7, 8, 9 or edge)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vb.net

Currently my application is compatible with only IE. The document mode is 5 by default (Please provide the reason for this). When I tried to implement some latest javascript features or jQuery, it does not work as IE5 does not provide support for these features. Hence why I wanted to push my application to run in a higher document mode.

I forced it using the below code and it worked.

`<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9'>`

Problem:
But all my CSS styles were impacted. Some style attributes had it's value changed and some CSS classes were not applied. Hence, my whole UI was destroyed.

My ultimate goal is to be able to code using latest javascript, jQuery, etc., and upgrade my application's UI.

Please help me identify the exact cause for the above behavior and a solution to overcome the same.

Comment: The meta tag does not change any code (it does not alter style attributes). It makes it incompatible, which we can not judge without seeing your code. Also IE9 is by far not latest JavaScript nor CSS. Usually the problem is, that IE9 is more strict and displays wrong definitions correct (=wrong for you) whereas elder version were displaying wrong definitions wrong (=correct for you).

Comment: To answer the title question: your style was wrong before, your browser just did not care. Now it does.

Comment: Yes. Run your CSS through a CSS validator (like [this one](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)) and correct the errors it finds. Also, IE5 dates from a long time back; you would find as many differences if you were to compare, say, Firefox 1 to its current-day successor.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have received clarity on the problem. I have one more doubt regarding the same behavior. Till date, I haven't coded anything with regards to document mode. But my application, by default emulates to document mode IE5. Can I know the reason for this behavior and if possible which piece of code forces this behavior?

Comment: There is a setting in IE to always display intranet sites in compatibility view. Could that be the problem on your end?

Comment: I am working on identifying the exact cause with all of your inputs. Will let you know once I find it. Thanks.